# SSIS package blocks itself if uses TRUNCATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, deadlock, truncate

There is an SSIS package with `Required` transaction on the package level and `Supported` on the tasks level. The main part of the package is deleting the data and inserting new data:

[image]

Here the *Delete* block deletes everything from six tables, and the *Parse* block loads six files to the six tables.

If the *Delete* uses `delete from dbo.table`, then everything works fine, but is slow.
But if *Delete* uses `truncate table dbo.table` instead, the deletion takes no time, but the package becomes blocked when it comes to the `Parse` task. Would just sit around doing nothing.

At this moment on the server side I can see an SSIS spid being blocked by spid `-2`, which is "Orphaned distributed transaction." It would appear that used to represent the truncating connection. This connection hangs around, and the package is blocked by the locks it placed.

If I switch the only used SQL Server Connection manager to `RetainSameConnection = True`, then the package fails as soon as it enters the *Parse* task. The task asks the manager for a connection, and the manager responds with

> [SQL Server Destination [471]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC001A004.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Is there a way to set up the package so that it uses `truncate` and does not block itself?

Comment: What about switching strategies altogether? Have a look at my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41158/2718) for what I mean. (The question asks about *moving* data, but the same sort of strategies can be applied to deletes as well.)

Comment: @GSerg have you tried setting sql task's property `ByPassPrepare` to `False` and package property `DelayValidation` to `True` ? Also, is the truncate table when you execute outside SSIS, still blocking ? Any other process running at the same time as Truncate requires SCH-M lock for deallocating the table allocation units.

Comment: I've used a truncate statement on the tables I'm loading data to with the transaction options as you describe. I'll let my brain cycle and see if any insight strikes

Comment: @JonSeigel An interesting solution, will tuck away for future use, but will probably not apply here.

Comment: @Kin Just tried that, made no difference. As for truncating outside SSIS, I don't really know, because I don't really use distributed transactions outside SSIS; within a non-distributed transaction it works, obviously.

Comment: @GSerg when you run the package, can you find out what is blocking by runing `sys.dm_exec_requests` ? That will help understand better the situation.

Comment: Found this KB article suggesting `ValidateExternalMetadata` to be set to FALSE. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2253391

Comment: @Kin `sys.dm_exec_requests` doesn't show what is blocking because it's `-2`. `ValidateExternalMetadata` solves the problem though, which is a bit surprising because all my OLE DB destinations already were 'Fast Load' which are said to be immune to the problem in the article.

Comment: @GSerg Perfect.. that due to how SSIS handles Distributed Trans. I will put that as an answer with some detailed explanation.

Comment: If you are using a Container change **TransanctionOption** property from Required to Supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to blocking caused by the `delete` task accessing the metadata from the database during the Pre-Execution phase.

The locks can be found using `sys.dm_tran_locks` and it will have `-2` value as OP founded. More details could have been found out using Profiler.

The blocking can be resolved by changing the `ValidateExternalMetadata` property to `FALSE` or as OP mentioned using a `DELETE` statement.

Reference: [**KB2253391**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2253391)

Comment: While the asnwer solves the problem, it does not really connect the dots nicely (and while I think I did connect them, I'm not entirely sure). So let me restate: The problem is that `truncate` will take schema-stability locks in addition to data locks, whereas `delete` will only take data locks. When later SSIS goes to validate the schema, it hits the taken schema-stability lock and waits because the connection that verifies metadata is intentionally not enlisted in the distributed transaction. With `delete` there is no problem because no schema locks were taken in the first place. Correct?